# How to use matplotlib from server?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a remote CentOS server running Python. Is there a way to display the matplotlib output on the computer than is running the shell without root privileges on the server? If that's confusing, here's a diagram:

```
   ========              =============
  | Server | --(ssh)--> | My computer |
   ========              =============
      |                        |
  Matplotlib             Visualization
 running here             output here
```

Comment: You might be able to use X forwarding. What OS is running on your local machine?

Comment: @Chris CentOS. Thanks for your prompt response!

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12772/12606

Comment: @Chris thanks, but I'm afraid I can't change the ssh config on the server. Is there still a way to use X forwarding?

Comment: Have you tried anyway? It may already be enabled.

Comment: Can you remote desktop or vnc into it?

Comment: @Chris I'll try, stand by

Comment: @Martin I don't think so, I doesn't even have a GUI

Comment: It's not a true answer to your question, but if all else fails you should be able to save your figures to the server and then use rsync/scp to copy them to your computer so you can view them there.